# webcam gives black after suspend

Tags: 13.04, skype, webcam

I was using skype when the computer automatically suspended/hibernated due to the battery condition. but when right after I switch on the computer and use skype all I get is a black screen from my webcam, the other party can't see a thing. I'm using ubuntu 13.04 64 bit version. Can you help me out, I installed cheese and it too gives me the black screen. thanks.

Comment: Try `sudo modprobe -r uvcvideo`, then `sudo modprobe uvcvideo`.

Comment: both of them executed without errors, but still getting the black screen

Comment: Do the first command, then `cheese`. Does it say "no device found"?

Comment: no error msgs. but before when I started cheese the indicator near the webcam  turned on, now when I did the first command and cheese the indicator keeps off.

Answer (score 1):

Since I cannot found a error or a fix for the problem, I tried switching off the lap by long-press power key and turn on again. Well, surprisingly it worked. :)